# IBDesignable from Storyboard not updating using cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ibdesignable

I have developed a cocoapods named `MRTextField`, it contains `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable`

The issue is when I am using pod in my another project, the `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` not working, also I think from storyboard it is not calling `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` of that component.

If I'm using from source code

```
let tf = MRTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 150, height: 40))
self.view.addSubview(tf)
```

It is working fine, but with custom class/storyboard it is not.

[image]

Designables is showing that it is up to date, but actually it is not.

[image]

After that I add MRTextField in Module, then it work fine.

I want to ask why user need to fill Module too? I use `JVFloatLabeledTextField`
 and it was working fine, i don't need to fill Module by myself. How do I make a pod where user don't need to fill Module, just he/she need to fill class?

Comment: There are some bugs in cocoapods ... check this link https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5334

Comment: I just worked with `PhoneNumberKit` using cocoapods, when I wrote in Custom Class `PhoneNumberKit` it automatically fills the module with `PhoneNumberKit`. Seems like I am doing something wrong.